# Unable to run automated testcases on e2e protractor,Angular 2

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to run a simple test but the test is failing because of the  Protractor is trying to sync with the page but cannot because it is not in Angular. Any ideas what needs to be changed?

Config File :

```
 exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

    specs            : [
     './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
     '/pages/**/*.Tracker_pageobject.ts',   
   ],

    capabilities     : {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect    : true,
    baseUrl          : 'http://localhost:4200/',
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    framework        : 'jasmine',
```

spec file:

```
describe('Test Application', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.get(environment.url + "/login");
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});


it('should not open login page when user enters invalid Username & Password', () => {
    var loginpage = new dashboard();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    loginpage.userName('abc');
    browser.sleep(2000);
    loginpage.password('cde');
    loginpage.loginbtn();
    element(by.className('mat-error ng-tns-c33-4 ng-star-inserted')).getText().then(function(value){
      browser.waitForAngular();
      browser.sleep(5000);
      console.log(value);
     });
    browser.sleep(5000);
 });
 it('should not open login page when user enters spaces', () => {
   browser.sleep(5000);
   var loginpage = new dashboard();
   loginpage.userName(' ');
   browser.sleep(2000);
   loginpage.password(' ');
   loginpage.loginbtn();
   element(by.className('mat-error ng-tns-c33-4 ng-star-inserted')).getText().then(function(value){
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.sleep(5000);
    console.log(value);
   });
   browser.sleep(5000);
 });
```

**loginpage(POM).ts**

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
var loginpage = function(){
var userNamefield = element(by.css("input[formcontrolname = 'email']"));
var passwordfield = element(by.css("input[formcontrolname = 'password']")); 
var loginbutton = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="login-form"]/form/button'));
var logoutbtn = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="main-navigation"]/fuse-nav-vertical-group/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a'));
this.userName = function(vusername){
    userNamefield.sendKeys(vusername);
};

this.password = function(vpassWord){
    passwordfield.sendKeys(vpassWord);
};

 this.loginbtn = function(btn){
     loginbutton.click();
};
```

Getting the below message:
**Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details**

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: try to not enable wait for angular, also why do you have page object class as test ?

Comment: i have a loginpage as POM and any substitute for waitForAngularEnabled()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all lines with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(....);` from `BeforeEach()`block in specs. And add `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to `onPrepare()` section in the `protractor.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

Change this block:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.get(environment.url + "/login");
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});
```

to this one:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.get(environment.url + "/login");
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
});
```

You don't need wait for Angular.
Also you probably need take a look at `Explicit waiters` in Selenium.

Comment: tried the mentioned solution but no luck still getting the same error

Comment: remove useAllAngular2AppRoots from protractor config.

Comment: remove all lines with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(....);` from `BeforeEach() block` in specs. And add `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to `onPrepare()` section in the `protractor.conf` file

Comment: Worked Thx a lot

Comment: @Shrutika I will post it as separate answer. Please, mark it as right.